# Can i use Thread isAlive method to change a state in my runnable to execute code?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have two buttons and when the user click the first one it will start a thread to update the UI, and when the user click the second one the app will set a boolean variable for the first thread to not allow it to update the thread and then it will start the second one. This is my Runnable :

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    boolean isUpdateEnabled = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Retrieve list from Internet. takes about 10 sec to complete.
        if (isUpdateEnabled) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.print("Update UI");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    void enableUpdate(boolean enable) {
        isUpdateEnabled = enable;
    }
}
```

but since the thread will take a time to complete, if the user press the first button again can i check if the first thread is alive and then enable it to update the thread while guarantee that the code inside `if (isUpdateEnabled)` will execute if or what the right way to do it?

```
    ...
    // on button click 
    if(thread.isAlive())
    runnable.enableUpdate(true);
    ...
```

Comment: should be fine, for safer usage I would advice to make the boolean variable volatile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you will need to do two things here :

1. Synchnorize access to isEnableUpdate, because two different threads are accessing it.
2. You may want to break your code in public void run into smaller chunks, and check the isEnableUpdate variable every once in a while when you finish some logical piece of work or something like that.

Sample :

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable 
{
 boolean isUpdateEnabled = true;
 Object myUpdateLockObj = new Object();

 @Override
 public void run() {
    // Retrieve list from Internet. takes about 10 sec to complete.
    if (isUpdateEnabled) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                lock(myUpdateLockObj)
                {
                   if (!isUpdateEnabled) return;
                }
                //do work in parts
                System.out.print("Update");

                lock(myUpdateLockObj)
                {
                   if (!isUpdateEnabled) return;
                }
                // do work in parts
                System.out.print(" UI");
            }
        });
    }
  }

  void enableUpdate(boolean enable) 
  {
    synhronized(myUpdateLockObj)
    {
        isUpdateEnabled = enable;
    }
  }
}
```